# Calling functions defined within the same object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an object that calls functions within itself but it seems that typescript is throwing some issue with the last function in the object.

Here's the typing and the imports:

```
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';

enum T {
    FileQuery = 'FileQuery',
    File = 'File',
    FileJSON = 'FileJSON'
}

interface FileQuery {
    path: string;
    encoding: string;
}

interface File {
    path: string;
    encoding: string;
    content: string;
}

interface FileJSON {
    path: string;
    encoding: string;
    content: string;
    data: any;
}
```

Here's the code itself

```
const f = {
    [`${T.FileQuery}To${T.File}`]: async (fileQuery: FileQuery): Promise<File> => {
        const { path, encoding } = fileQuery;
        const content = await fs.readFile(path, encoding);
        return { ...fileQuery, content }
    },
    [`${T.File}To${T.FileJSON}`]: (file: File): FileJSON => {
        const data = JSON.parse(file.content);
        return { ...file, data }
    },
    [`${T.FileQuery}To${T.FileJSON}`]: (fileQuery: FileQuery): FileJSON => {
        const file = f[`${T.FileQuery}To${T.File}`](fileQuery)
        return f[`${T.File}To${T.FileJSON}`](file);
    }
}
```

Also tried this and it did not work either:

```
const f = {
    async  [`${T.FileQuery}To${T.File}`] (fileQuery: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
        const { path, encoding } = fileQuery;
        const content = await fs.readFile(path, encoding);
        return { ...fileQuery, content }
    },
    [`${T.File}To${T.FileJSON}`] (file: File): FileJSON {
        const data = JSON.parse(file.content);
        return { ...file, data }
    },
    [`${T.FileQuery}To${T.FileJSON}`] (fileQuery: FileQuery): FileJSON {
        const file = f[`${T.FileQuery}To${T.File}`](fileQuery)
        return f[`${T.File}To${T.FileJSON}`](file);
    }
}
```

However this does work without type errors:

```
const f = {}

f[`${T.FileQuery}To${T.File}`] = async (fileQuery: FileQuery): Promise<File> => {
    const { path, encoding } = fileQuery;
    const content = await fs.readFile(path, encoding);
    return { ...fileQuery, content }
}

f[`${T.File}To${T.FileJSON}`] = (file: File): FileJSON => {
    const data = JSON.parse(file.content);
    return { ...file, data }
}

f[`${T.FileQuery}To${T.FileJSON}`] = (fileQuery: FileQuery): FileJSON => {
    const file = f[`${T.FileQuery}To${T.File}`](fileQuery)
    return f[`${T.File}To${T.FileJSON}`](file);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use computed property names with constant strings? The IDE couldn't help you, neither the TypeScript compiler. You could simply write the property names: `FileQueryToFile`, `FileToFileJSON`, `FileQueryToFileJSON`. Then your code will be easier to read and to understand for both humans and developer tools.

Comment: Your last solution compiles because you loose types. But without type checking, the TS compiler doesn't help anymore. The third function must be asynchronous, the call of the first one needs an `await`. Just write your object normally and you'll see it.